# how to pass a variable through a constructor in java

Tags: java, android, class, parameters, constructor

I want to pass a variable  to String filename variable below as a parameter. Can anyone help?? I checked the internet but could not find a good tutorial or example.
Thank you in advance...

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class JavaReadTextFile
{
    public static String main(String[] args)
    {
        // This instantiates from another class 
        ReadFile rf = new ReadFile();

        // The text file location of your choice.
        // Here I want to pass a variable as a parameter to the variable filename
        String filename = "";

        try
        {
            String[] lines = rf.readLines(filename);

            for (String line : lines)
            {
                //System.out.println(line);
                return line;
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            // Print out the exception that occurred
            System.out.println("Unable to create " + filename + ": " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your class does not have an explicit constructor. By "passing a variable", you mean you want to pass it as command line parameter?

Comment: Additionally, please put more effort into formatting code when you post it. I'll edit your post this time, but please review what it looks like before posting, and ask yourself whether that's the way you'd want to see it.

Comment: `//Here I want to pass a variable as a parameter to the variable filename` The variable filename is a String how exactly you want to pass a variable to that? Or you mean you want to attribute the value of a variable to filename?

Comment: you want to use command line argument for passing the parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean "as an argument to my program", so that you can run:

```
java -jar myProgram.java theStringIWantToPass
```

If so, that's what `main(String[] args)` is for. All arguments will be put in there.. So, try using the following:

```
if (args.length > 0){
    filename = args[0];
}
```

Comment: @Andreas Right... Too much C influence in my life. Fixed it, thanks for pointing that one out.

Comment: Thank you all . This one did it. Sorry for late message...:)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post a constructor, but you can get the (command line) parameter of your main function:

```
public static String main(String[] args) {
    if (args!=null && args.length > 0) {
         String filename = args[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
String filename = args[0];
```

Now you can pass the file name as a program argument.

Answer (score -3):

If you are open to use swing , then you can explore JOptionPane mesageBox , which can take input.

Otherwise the conventional way of reading the arguments while running the program from args array.